# Algolia - WordPress custom ranking attribute by taxonomy / term

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I have list of events that are correctly indexed into Algolia. I would like to be able to "order by" taxonomy/term.

1) first taxonomy is called events_weight (5 terms 1,2,3,4,5). I need the events to be able to order by the term displaying the ones that are 1 at the top and those that are 5 in the bottom. Is this at all possible?

2) second taxonomy is called events_status (active, inactive, promotion). Again I need to be able to order them. Promotion first, then active, then inactive. Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your Algolia Dashboard, you can add the `events_weight` attributes as custom ranking.

For `events_status`, I would recommend you to convert the values to an integer, to use it as a custom ranking (or sorting).

You can add them both and decide which one go first. This video explains Algolia's [tie breaking algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6crAohtUBw).

Comment: Julien you have point there. Events status can be converted to 0 and 1, or can be treated as true or false. 

However this all falls on the fact that I can not see the taxonomy in the Algolia backend in section Ranking Formula & Custom Ranking. Do I have to do anything special to add the taxonomy as ranking formula item?